# Equivalent to search within IEnumerable with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a shorter, elegant way to write the following using LINQ?

```
 var actorName = string.Empty;
 foreach (var myProperty in myProperties)
 {
       if (myProperty .PropertyName == "ActorName")
       {
             actorName = myProperty .PropertyValue;
             break;

       }

  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var actorName = myProperties
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyName == "ActorName")
                .PropertyValue;
```

This would give a NPE if nothing could be found though (`FirstOrDefault` returns `null` as default).

To combat this, use two statements instead:

```
var actor = myProperties
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyName == "ActorName");

var actorName = actor == null ? string.Empty : actor.PropertyValue;
```

Comment: Wait.. what if "Default" happens?

Comment: Easiest solution would be to use two statements and check for a `null` value. I can't immediatly come up with a way to check this inline, so I'll wait and see if someone else does. I'll remove this if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jeroen's answer.. its safer to check for `null` first.. since `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` when there is nothing that matches:

```
var actor = myProperties
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyName == "ActorName");

if (actor != null)
    actorName = actor.PropertyValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

Pure LINQ version, for the hell of it, though I'd prefer Simon's answer.

```
var actorName = myProperties
    .Where(x => x.PropertyName == "ActorName")
    .Select(x => x.PropertyValue)
    .Concat(new[]{ string.Empty })
    .First();
```